# Sort list descending order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, for-loop, arraylist

**Sort the list record in JavaScript in desc order**

```javascript
var number; //here we are getting dynamic number from API

var test; //here we are getting dynamic text from API

for (var i; i <= accList.length; i++) {
  var odlist = 'you have :' + test + number + 

  dataList.push(odlist);
}
```

Current output:

```
1.you have : total 4 accounts of 10

2.you have : total 11 account accounts of 23 

3.you have : total 0 accounts of 100

4. you have : total 2 accounts of 6
```

Now I want to sort above list in descending order looking for output as per below:

```
1.you have : total 0 accounts of 100

2.you have : total 11 account accounts of 23 

3.you have : total 4 accounts of 10

4.you have : total 2 accounts of 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var reversed = dataList.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Array.prototype.sort` with a comparison function
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort

But I'm not fully understanding your code.

```js
const dataList = ["1.you have : total 4 accounts of 10",
"2.you have : total 11 account accounts of 23",
"3.you have : total 0 accounts of 100",
"4. you have : total 2 accounts of 6"]

const reg = /(\d+)$/;

dataList.sort((a, b) => {
    const avalue = reg.exec(a)[0]
  const bvalue = reg.exec(b)[0]
    return +bvalue > +avalue
}).forEach(s => document.write(s + "<br />"))
```

Comment: Thanks-Romain but above link not help me to resolve my issue. Is there any other way to sort the list of string including?

Comment: It can. I'm understanding that you want to sort on number included in a string. Use regular expression in the comparison function to extract the numbers and making the sort on these values

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmpArr = []
for (id in dataList) {
    tmpArr.push(dataList[id].split(' ').reverse())
}
tmpArr.sort((a,b) => (a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1))
dataList = []
for (id in tmpArr) {
    dataList.push(tmpArr[id].reverse().join(' '))
}
```

But still, your approach to the problem is wrong, you should sort values before output.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dataList = ["teyuwdh 10", "hsdhcksj 100", "euwfhiuweic 1"];

dataList.sort(
    function(a, b) {return b.match(/\d+$/) - a.match(/\d+$/)}
);

console.log('dataList: ' + JSON.stringify(dataList));
```

output: dataList: ["hsdhcksj 100","teyuwdh 10","euwfhiuweic 1"]